# Hide specific methods of a typed class in a smart pointer

Tags: c++, stl, com, shared-ptr, iunknown

I use the following code

```
template <typename T> std::shared_ptr<T> comToShared(T* comObject) {
    comObject->AddRef();
    return std::shared_ptr<T>(comObject, [=](auto) {
        comObject->Release();
    });
}
```

to convert a COM object into a shared_ptr, as that fits better with the rest of my codebase. The problem is that I still can (and occasionally do) call `AddRef()` or `Release()` on the interior pointer and cause an over-release/over-retain issue.

Is there a way to hide just those two methods in this case so that using them causes a compile error whilst leaving the rest of the interface accessible?

Comment: You could make `comToShared` a friend of each type COM class you want to call `comToShared` on, if the stray invocations of `AddRef` and `Release` are occurring in places that don't otherwise have access to private members of `T`.

Comment: No. Unless you can within class declare the methods to be protected and declare a bunch of friend classes that would AddRef/Release when needed. Not sure if COM can work with that though.

Comment: Can just not call AddRef/Release? If needed create an additional class that calls on creation AddRef and Release on destruction - this way you'll never over- or under- release. This is similar to lock guard with mutexes. You can also just write a COM smart pointer instead of using shared ptr that will call AddRef for smart pointer instance.

Comment: Most COM frameworks in C++ already provide their own smart pointers for managing COM object pointers. Just as raw pointers in C++ should only be used for read-only views and smart pointers used everywhere else, the same is true in COM when used in C++.